# Searching Gerrit by Commit Message

Tags: gerrit

Our team uses a standard of prefixing all commit messages with "bz12345:" (where 12345 is replaced by the bug you're working on) and I'd like to be able to search for all commits that have that bug number.

I've read http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.6/user-search.html over and over and haven't figured out a way to search for commit message titles.  Does anybody have a trick for searching the first line of a commit message for arbitrary text?  None of message:, tr:, and bug: work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out.  You MUST have a `status:` query too.  For example, this **works**:

```
status:merged message:bz12345
```

This does **not**:

```
message:bz12345
```

This could be because we're on an older version of Gerrit (2.2.1 I think).

Comment: The necessity to add `status:merged` (and limitation that you cannot search both merged and open) exists in Gerrit 2.7 too. Hopefully it is removed in some future versions. I think i saw this working *correctly* though I don't know which version fixes this.

Answer (score 7):

message:bz12345 should work.

See the [latest documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#_search_operators)

Note that it searches the whole message body though, not just the subject.

> message:'MESSAGE'
>
> Changes that match MESSAGE arbitrary string in the commit message body.