# Is it possible to search for commit by Change-Id in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

Gerrit generated a Change-Id in commit message. Is it possible to search for a commit by this Change-Id?

Comment: Yes, since it's part of the commit message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409413/searching-gerrit-by-commit-message

Comment: Thanks. The link you provided does solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is search by "message:" instead of "change:". Change-Id is part of the commit message and searchable. "change:" must refer to some other field.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this search using the [Gerrit query](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html) command line.

All forms below are equivalent:

- `ssh -p 29418 your.gerrit.com gerrit query --format=JSON 8958202`
- `ssh -p 29418 your.gerrit.com gerrit query --format=JSON change:'8958202'`
- `ssh -p 29418 your.gerrit.com gerrit query --format=JSON change:'I3054034b91597e54f84f3fa2c4afbcc9f8b60e63'`

Tested with gerrit v2.14

Answer (score 0):

I found this easy way :

```
https://<your.gerrit.com>/plugins/gitiles/<BranchName>/+/<CommitID>
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: the CommitID in the url is not the change-id on git, but an internal gerrit identifier. with the git change-id (and especially one of its substrings) it doesn't work